# Array of time to fill a simpleform listbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a time field and would like to have only the following times appear:

09:00
09:15
09:30
09:45
10:00
...
14:00

I'm using Simple_Forms, bootstrap and activerecord.

Last thing I tried was setting up a global initialiser like this:

```
ValidHours =
['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', 
  '11:00', '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00',
  '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00']
```

and then in Simple_Forms I used:

```
  <%= f.input :order_until_hour, :label => "Order until", :collection => ValidHours %>
```

This displays the values correctly but they don't seem to be saved in the database.

If possible I would also like to have this info in the model where it belongs.

I also tried:

```
def self.ValidHours
  ['09:00', '09:15', '09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00',
    '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '12:45', '13:00', 
    '13:15', '13:30', '13:45', '14:00']
end
```

and in the view:

```
  <%= f.input :order_until_hour, :label => "Order until", :collection => ValidHours %>
```

but that didn't work either.

Thanks for any clues!

EDIT:

Thanks for the reply uDaY.  I tried your suggestion.

They appear correctly now, I also checked the database and they get saved too.  However if I click on edit (after it's saved) it still appears empty.

This is the code:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.ValidHours
      [['09:00', '09:00'], ['09:15', '09:15'], ['09:30', '09:30'], ['09:45', '09:45'], ['10:00', '10:00'],
       ['10:15', '10:15'], ['10:30', '10:30'], ['10:45', '10:45'], ['11:00', '11:00'], ['11:15', '11:15'],
       ['11:30', '11:30'], ['11:45', '11:45'], ['12:00', '12:00'],
       ['12:15', '12:15'], ['12:30', '12:30'], ['12:45', '12:45'], ['13:00', '13:00'], ['13:15', '13:15'],
       ['13:30', '13:30'], ['13:45', '13:45'], ['14:00', '14:00']]
  end
```

and in the view:

```
      <%= f.input :order_until_hour, :label => "Order until", :collection => Shop.ValidHours %>
```

In the database the values appear as:

```
order_until_hour: "2000-01-01 09:00:00"
```

so I thought I would alter the ValidHours like this:

```
  def self.ValidHours
      [['09:00', '2000-01-01 09:00'], ['09:15', '2000-01-01 09:15'] …
```

but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: rate my answer if it works! ;)

Comment: You should change your view so that :value => :order_until_hour.strftime("%H:%M") or something like that.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply.  I get this now:   
    undefined method `strftime' for :order_until_hour:Symbol
Do I need to include something else?  I'm pretty new to rails sorry.

Comment: Hi Jason, I finally figured it out:

It's :selected instead of :value

      <%= f.input :order_until_hour, :label => "Order until", :collection => Shop.ValidHours, :selected => @shop.order_until_hour.to_s.to_datetime.strftime("%H:%M")  %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `key` which is the text that is displayed in the dropdown but the `value` is not there so you have do something like this:

```
def self.ValidHours
  [['09:00','09:00'], ['09:15','09:15'], ['09:30','09:30'],['09:45','09:45'],['10:00','10:00'],['10:15','10:15'],['10:30','10:30'], ['10:45','10:45'],['11:00','11:00']]
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to change the view also to:
      <%= f.input :order_until_hour, :label => "Order until", :collection => Shop.ValidHours, :selected => @shop.order_until_hour.to_s.to_datetime.strftime("%H:%M")  %>